# Calculating intraday candlesticks by time intervals

Tags: java, math, candlestick-chart

This maybe an over asked question, but my mind draws blank at this moment. I know what a [candlestick chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) is and how to draw it daily. But how to draw it intraday at asked time periods. I have this server, written in Java, that gives me trade depth (each trade done since the start of the day). Its just a stream of raw data: price, shares, timestamp.

How does one go about calculating candlestick data from that? Lets say, they want to have 5 min candlestick or 1min candlestick. Or is there a library that will do that for me if I feed it data?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you would have to find the hi/lo for your 5 minutes/one min whatever (I guess you have the open/close.  Then you feed the hi/lo/open/close to some API that can draw candlesticks... Or you write your own.  Note that JFreeChart is one the piggiest pig of an API around: its slowness is disgusting and its author has pretty much acknowledge in the JFreeChart forums that JFreeCharts wasn't really top-notch when it came to dealing with a lot of data updated in real-time (for example you cannot add data "at the right" of a chart in JFreeChart: you have to redraw everything).  Pick your poison :)

Comment: I've taken a look at JFreeChart and it only does the drawing. So that one problem down. But I'm still not sure how to calculate the values. Say if I have a array of the values. How to group them into the time intervals. In SQL I'd use GROUP BY and specify the interval. But my mind is blank on how to do that in Java. I guess I can iterate over the elements and use a stack to calculate the open, close, high, low and average price? Hmm...

Answer (score 2):

The exact implementation varies depending on how you're storing the data, but in general:

1. Sort the data by timestamp
2. Decide when the day starts (e.g. 9 AM EST, whatever) and find the timestamp of that time on the first day. You then know when each 5 minute (or whatever) bar begins and ends, by adding an appropriate offset to that number.
3. Find the index of the first data point that is not in the first bar - every data point whose index is lower than that is in the first bar. It's now straightforward to take the first, last, maximum, and minimum prices for a candlestick.
4. Repeat 3, substituting the last index of the previous candle for 0.

You now have the data partitioned into candles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) ? It will draw [candlesticks](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartCandlestickDemo.htm), and since it's incredibly configurable, it may well do what you want.